# How to clear p:inputText on second call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:inputText>` tag in a dialog. When I enter value and submit it for the first time, it saves the value in the backing bean. But when I open the dialog for the second time, the earlier value in the `<p:inputText>` still holds. How can I clear input textbox when I open the dialog for the second or subsequent times?

Answer (score 2):

Clear binded value in the backing bean and do an `update="idOfDialog"` on your `<p:commandButton/>`.